# kweb3 projeckktor raspberry pi memory leak

Tags: raspberry-pi, html5-video, virtual-memory, kiosk-mode, projekktor

I am using Kweb3 in kiosk mode with projekktor on raspberry pi to play html5 mp4 video files. The time I play 5-6 files, it keeps on increasing virtual memory & hence the time it reaches 500mb, browser start showing loader & nothing happens (basically goes out of memory/memory leak is happening). How can this memory issue be fixed? it is not removing the older video from memory. I also tried the iframe way of doing it. no luck. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I note your question was asked a long time but there is a solution to this.

We had the same problem and the solution is to:

- Play the video in an iframe within your application
- When the video has finished, remove the iframe from the DOM

This effectively creates a fresh page and then destroys that page once it is removed. This causes it to be freed up from memory.

We were able to play 12 videos consecutively (in a single page app) after finally finding this fix.